# Looping through structure in matlab to sort

Tags: matlab, structure

I have a structure with 7 fields. In each cell of the 7th field there is a date. I need a nested loop to sort through those dates and if any of those dates do not exist in the 2nd field of the same structure I would like to take that information (from all 7 fields) and create a new structure containing only the iterations that has dates in the 2nd field but not the 7th. The code that I have so far is:

```
for i=1:12 %number of dates in the 7th field
    for j=1:length(files_cdf) %number of dates in the 2nd field
        y(i,j)=isequal(files_cdf(j).date,files_cdf(i).deletables);
        if isequal(y(i,j),0)
            cdf(j)=files_cdf(j);
        end
    end
end
```

But it copies my entire original structure into the new structure without removing the unwanted information. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into the `setdiff` function ?

Comment: I don't think it works for structures.... I have tried and failed.

Comment: If the elements `files_cdf(j).date` and `files_cdf(i).deletables` are scalar, I think you can get a logical mask via `all(bsxfun(@ne,[files_cdf(:).date].',[files_cdf(:).deletables]),2)`.  But without runable code, I can't test it.

Comment: An error comes up "Operands must be numeric arrays."

Comment: The description of your question is what is confusing me. If you include what your structure looks like in the workspace it may be easier to understand. I think you are dealing with a vector of structs but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the loops can be eliminated through some vectorization via `bsxfun` assuming the elements are scalars of type `datetime`:

```
% Convert to double
second  = datenum([files_cdf(:).date].');
seventh = datenum([files_cdf(:).deletables]);
%
% Make logical mask
mask = all(bsxfun(@ne,second,seventh),2)
%
% Mask struct array
cdf = files_cdf(mask);
```